# Core data versioning/migration after deleting entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-migration, versioning

I have a database which consists of 3 entities, say 
*'IronMan', 'CaptainAmerica' and 'SpiderMan'*.
With new changes, I want to delete all three entities and create another entity called 'Thanos'.

I would not need to use any of the code and data stored earlier with entities *'IronMan', 'CaptainAmerica' and 'SpiderMan'*. Do I need to do core data versioning or migration in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Apple's documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration

> You can add, remove, and rename entities in the hierarchy.

So, yes, you need to provide migration (new version model) but can stick to a light-weight migration, hence it will be done automatically based on changes done between the 2 models.